# "Guess the 2/3 of average" game

Tags: game-theory

Let us consider the game "Guess the  2/3  of average"

(description: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guess_2/3_of_the_average)

I know, the strategy profile where all players play $0$ is a Nash equilibrium. But how do we know it is the only Nash equilibrium in this game? Iterated elimnation of weakly dominated strategies doesn't guarantee us that or am I missing something?

Comment: Description here please (no link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that if all the other players strategies are unchanged, and I have the strategy X (different from chosing 0 everytime), the strategy "chosing the number given by the strategy X minus one (or 0 if the strategy X gives me 0)" is always better.

Hence, the strategy X can be improved, and we're not in a Nash equilibrium

Comment: So in that case iterated elimination of weakly dominated strategies leads us to unique nash equilibirum. But in general case iterated elimination of weakly dominated strategies can omit some of nash equilibria

Comment: Your comment is correct @luka5z.